# How to override shortcodes.php core file?

Tags: plugins

I would like to override/update to core shortcodes.php file. Build an array and send data differently to other functions, but my question is how to do that without editing the core file? Is there a best practice way overriding core files and/or functions?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a shortcode you want to override and what you want to override it with?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "override" whole files or functions, except in special circumstances. That is basic PHP.

WordPress has code in place that will let you override particular files and functions. For example, child themes can override parent theme files. That is because of the way the WordPress Template loader works. The override only works if the files load via that mechanism. Those files are meant to be overridden. Core files are not.

WordPress also has a number of functions in `pluggable.php` that are wrapped in a `if ( !function_exists('some_function_name') ) :` conditional. If you declare a function with an identical name before that file loads, then your function will be used and not the default. Again, those are meant to be overridden.

And some hooks let you replace callback functions.

Otherwise you can't override files and functions. You need to find another way to do what you want. Maybe that involves hooks, but you will need to did through the source to find the hooks you need.

For shortcodes in particular, you can remove shortcodes individually with [`remove_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode), and then [replace them with your own](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) but you can also clobber/hijack another shortcode just by registering another one with the same "tag".

Proof of concept:

```
function test_sc($atts,$content) {
  return 'Howdy';
}
add_shortcode('testsc','test_sc');

function clobber_test_sc($atts,$content) {
  return 'Hi';
}
add_shortcode('testsc','clobber_test_sc');
```

However, `shortcodes.php` doesn't actually contain shortcodes. It contains the shortcode support functions-- the API. Those are not meant to be meddled with, and there are no hooks that I spotted.

As far as "Build an array and send data differently to other functions", I don't even know what that means but my guess would be that you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) are a way to override core files

Or

Write your own [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and remove default one.

[shortcodes.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L0) is a simple set of functions for creating macro codes for use in post/page content.
like [gallery]

Comment: Which hook covers my problem? Because I didn't found anything useful in that list.

Comment: Like wordpress default widget text-widget, it not execute shortcodes.but wordpress provide filter by which we can alter its's behaviour and force it to execute shortcode( for ex. add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');) [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) , dig into wordpress shortcode.php or wordpress codex to find for hook for your shortcode

Comment: Thank you. And if I write a function in functions.php how can be called to shortcodes.php functions?

Comment: Read more about wordpress hooks.when wordpress execute a shortcode, It also execute action and filter on it. and then return a final output.wordpress take care of all code in functions.php.