# Add gallery id to rel attribe of wp_get_attachment_link

Tags: functions, gallery, links

Now i have this snippet in my functions.php

```
/**
 * Add rel to links.
 */
function add_rel_to_gallery($link) {
    return str_replace('<a href=', '<a data-fancybox="true" rel="group" href=', $link);
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_rel_to_gallery' );
```

Every link in gallery has **rel="group"**, but actually i want get something like that:

```
rel="group-$gallery-id"
```

How do this?

**What is gallery id?**

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-1457 gallery-columns-5 gallery-size-thumbnail">
    <dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a data-fancybox="true" rel="group" href="smt.jpg"><img src="smt.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="ult-collection_sh10154" height="150" width="150"></a>
      </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a data-fancybox="true" rel="group" href="smt.jpg"><img src="smt.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="ult-collection_sh10153_1" height="150" width="150"></a>
      </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

In this output gallery id is 1457.

I need gallery id (or something that can grouped images from one gallery to one rel group) for create fancybox groups:

> Note: ID's are single use and are only applied to one element.
>   Galleries are created from elements who have the same "data-fancybox-group" or "rel" attribute value.

via http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

**To @s_ha_dum:**

```
function add_rel_to_gallery($link, $id) {
  return str_replace('<a href=', '<a data-fancybox="true" rel="group-'.$id.'" href=', $link);
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_rel_to_gallery', 10, 2 );
```

Output:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-1457 gallery-columns-5 gallery-size-thumbnail"><dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a data-fancybox="true" rel="group-1461" href="http://streetball.name/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ult-collection_sh10153_1.jpeg"><img src="http://streetball.name/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ult-collection_sh10153_1-150x150.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="ult-collection_sh10153_1" height="150" width="150"></a>
      </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a data-fancybox="true" rel="group-1467" href="http://streetball.name/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ult-collection_sh10348_1.jpeg"><img src="http://streetball.name/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ult-collection_sh10348_1-150x150.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="ult-collection_sh10348_1" height="150" width="150"></a>
      </dt></dl>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is `$gallery`?

Comment: @kaiser i add explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That filter passes more arguments than you are using](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1207).

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', "<a href='$url'>$link_text</a>", $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text );
```

The second of those is the one you need. So you need to alter you callback to use the second parameter, and alter your `add_filter` to ask for it by setting the fourth argument to 2.

```
function add_rel_to_gallery($link, $id) {
  return str_replace('<a href=', '<a data-fancybox="true" rel="group-'.$id.'" href=', $link);
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_rel_to_gallery', 10, 2 );
```

After seeing your edit, I realized that I misread what you were attempting and I tried to find a way to create a static gallery specific ID without abusing hooks too much. I am not sure I succeeded in that last part but the following seems to work:

```
function get_id($inc = false) {
  static $id;
  if ($inc) {
    $id++;
  }
  return $id;
}

function replace($link) {
  $id = get_id();
  return str_replace('<a href=', '<a data-fancybox="true" rel="group-'.$id.'" href=', $link);
}

add_filter(
  'post_gallery',
  function() {
    get_id(true);
    add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link','replace');
  }
);
```

The correct answer is probably to use the [`post_gallery` hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L685) to hijack the rest of the gallery shortcode, or [just overwrite the gallery shortcode with one of your own](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100345/21376).

Comment: Actually, for every link i get unique ID.

Comment: Please, see post update.