# Override the Wordpress core function wp_referer_field

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, actions

I'd like to override the core Wordpress function wp_referer_field to change the value of  $referer_field variable inside of it. 
I've found that wp_referer_field is not pluggable and that I need to use some other technics for that. Adding some filters or actions.
 I was trying to use these code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_referer_field' , 'wp_referer_field_cyrillic' );
function wp_referer_field_cyrillic( $echo = true ) {
   $referer_field = '<input type="hidden" name="_my_wp_http_referer" value="'.urldecode(esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )) . '" />';
   if ( $echo )
     echo $referer_field;
   return $referer_field;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It seems that I did something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_referer_field` is a *function*. You cannot treat a function like a *hook*. That isn't how hooks work. That is, you can't hook into a function name. Hooks are intentionally created. ([And there are no hooks built into that function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1258))

Secondly, you can't override a function at all, as a rule. Some few functions in WordPress are wrapped in an `if(function_exists('..'))` conditional. Those are the exceptions. Those can be replaced by creating a new function of the same name, but not by "hooking" into them.

There may be another way to do what you are trying to do if you were to explain the problem in more detail.

See:

- [Override parent theme function that is not hooked or in the functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101238/override-parent-theme-function-that-is-not-hooked-or-in-the-functions-php-file/101240#101240)
- [How to override shortcodes.php core file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100334/how-to-override-shortcodes-php-core-file/100345#100345)
- [Clarification on filters and hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103641/clarification-on-filters-and-hooks/103644#103644)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, the referer value is a security field. If you change it arbitrarily, you'll very likely break your site completely, since it's checked on form submissions and the like.