# Shortcodes: override a shortcode / change shortcode on the fly

Tags: shortcode, multi-language

I've done a plugin where you can add shortcode like this: `[myplugin xx]` (where `xx` is a number which calls a specific content `xx`).

I have to do a multilingual version of my plugin, so here's my trick: my client writes content `xx` for language #1 and content `yy` for language #2.

Then, in an article, he would have to add something like:

```
[multilingualmyplugin #1 xx][multilingualmyplugin #2 yy]
```

and then I should just have to write a plugin that is called and change the content *before* Wordpress calls my first plugin to either `[myplugin xx]` or `[myplugin yy]` depending on the domain name. Then Wordpress would call the plugin.

Is it possible and if so, where should I look?

Comment: why not just set two attributes in a single shortcode and handle both cases from that one shortcode handler?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the question, but maybe... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100345/21376

Comment: Could you use a php if statement to detect language and display the correct shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done:created a shortcode where I do `[myplugin language="fr" id="5"][myplugin language="us" id="8"]` and then, when this page is called, it calls myplugin twice. If it's *not* on the right page, my plugin returns nothing. So, when this page is called:

- if it's on a domain like "mydomain.fr" I just call `do_shortcode("othershortcode 5")`
- if it's on a domain like "mydomain.us" I just call `do_shortcode("othershortcode 8")`

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode can accept parameters

Here how I did it:

```
[multilingualmyplugin en_content="22" fr_content="33"]
```

Then in the shortcode function, you can use if statement:

```
if($subdomain==='en'){
    //Return content with id $attr['en_content']
}
else if(subdomain==='fr'){
    //Return content with id $attr['fr_content']
}
else{
    //Return something else
}
```